# Resize an Array in Java with same name

Tags: java, arrays, resize, stack

I'm trying to resize an array to my 'push' method, but in the output the number '6' it's not there.

Any clue?

```
public void push(int value) {
        if (size != maxSize){ 
            top++;
            stackArray[top] = value;
            size++;
        }else if (size == maxSize){
            stackArray = Arrays.copyOf(stackArray, size * 2);
            maxSize = size * 2;
            size++;
        }else{
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
```

Pop method

```
public int pop() {
        if (size != 0){
            size--;
            return stackArray[top--];
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
```

I put some elements on that stack

```
Stack theStack= new Stack(5);

    theStack.push(1);
    theStack.push(2);
    theStack.push(3);
    theStack.push(4);
    theStack.push(5);
    theStack.push(6);
    theStack.push(7);

    System.out.println(theStack.pop());
    System.out.println(theStack.pop());
    System.out.println(theStack.pop());
    System.out.println(theStack.pop());
    System.out.println(theStack.pop());
    System.out.println(theStack.pop());
```

And then i've got this

7
   5
   4
   3
   2
   1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case `size == maxSize`, you don't add 6 after resizing the array. Please modify your method to something like this.

Now, you are resizing first (if required). Then do your insertion as normal.

```
public void push(int value) {
    // resize if required
    if (size == maxSize){
        stackArray = Arrays.copyOf(stackArray, size * 2);
        maxSize = size * 2;
    }

    // then do the addition to the array stuff
    if (size != maxSize){ 
        top++;
        stackArray[top] = value;
        size++;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to move up the `RuntimeException()`. Up to you. :)

Comment: It worked, i was resizing in the 'else'. Thanks mate!

Comment: @MateusLuiz It would be nice, if you could accept/upvote an answer if your issue is resolved. From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."